# How can I transfer data from running hyperledgerfabric blockchain to new hyperledgerFabric blockchain?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, blockchain

I have running  hyperLedgerFabric blockchain network and I want to transfer data to new hyperLedgerFabric blockchain

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

You can write a client application that uses the block event service to read all the blocks from the first chain, iterate over the transaction write sets within each block, and for each submit a transaction to the new chain. See the block event service [sample](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/tree/main/off_chain_data) that iterates over all transactions.